# Error while building docker image : container_linux.go:344: starting container process

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, containers

I am having a docker file

```
FROM someimage:latest as my-image
```

It was able to build fine for a long time.

```
sudo docker build --target my-image
```

However, accidentally , now it has started giving error:

```
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Comment: Using `xxx:latest` means it will always pull the latest version of the base image. Lock it to a specific version could solve the problem if it works well before.

Comment: By the way, could you please also share the Dockerfile to your post?